# Sending a post httpclient request in Titanium

Tags: javascript, post, titanium, appcelerator, onload

```
var xhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload:function(e){
    if(this.status == '200'){
          Ti.API.info('got my response, http status code ' + this.status);
           if(this.readyState == 4){
                var response=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                success = true;
                }
            else{
                alert('HTTP Ready State != 4');
            }           
        }
        else{
            alert('HTTP Error Response Status Code = '+this.status);
            Ti.API.error("Error =>"+this.response);
        }              
    },

});
xhr.onerror = function(e){ 
};

xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:23003/api/user?username=dp&password=123456" ,true);//ADD your URL

xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");

xhr.send();  // Taa da
```

Hi there, The above mentioned is my code, I am trying to send a post request to a local server process as mentioned in the *open* method. But I used some console messages to see these to objects that were returned

1. this.responseText -- This text is blank. (I know java script returns null differently and the alert message displays 'null' as null.)
2. this.status -- returns '0'
3. this.readyState  returns 4
4. var response = JSON.parse(); is a blank text
5. I have tried changing the content type to -application/x-www-form-urlencoded too but I get the same results

I have no idea where I'm wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: a/ you could try to change *localhost* in url to your *ip address*.

b/ try checking the the webservice using [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to confirm that webservice is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something is wrong with your server-side code because the following:

```
  var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
      console.info(this.status);
      console.info(this.readyState);
      console.info(this.responseText);
    }
  });
  xhr.open("POST", "http://requestb.in/ynwa0gyn");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.send();
```

Correctly gives:

```
[INFO]  200
[INFO]  4
[INFO]  ok
```

Visit http://requestb.in/ynwa0gyn?inspect for the request made by the client.

Comment: Do you think it could be something to do with my local firewall or something else?

Comment: It could. You'll have to find a way to see how the request comes in on your server and see if that is correct or not.

Comment: Do you think a browser security setting or a windows security setting is doing this?

Comment: Its a CORS issue. I went through this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/. I have to set up the server to handle a CORS request and client should include a few extra headers mentioned in the link. Or one can use the android or Iphone simulator/emulators to run this. This is a purely browser security hurdle.